# Code breakes while reading resultset returned by DyanmoDb's table.scan() in python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, resultset

I'm really new at dynamoDB, so question might be very stupid.
My purpose and code is very simple:

1. I connect to DynamoDB.
2. I get desired Table back from dynamoDB
3. I read all values via Table.scan()
4. but when i try to run for loop on returned resultset obtained at step 3 instead of iterating through resulset I fail with following error:
   **TypeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

Here is my code:

```
     def fireQuery(tableName):
         table = getTable(tableName)
         try :
              result = table.scan(Select="ALL_ATTRIBUTES")
              for item in result['Items'] :  #<-- my code fails here
                  print(item)

     def getTable(tableName):
         try:
              db = getDynamoDBConnection()
              table = Table(tableName, connection=db)        
         except Exception as e:
              print(tableName ," Table doesn't exist.", e)
         return table
```

Exception on console:

***for item in users['Items'] :***

***TypeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute '__getitem__'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate the ResultSet like this:

```
def fireQuery(tableName):
    table = getTable(tableName)
    try :
         result_set = table.scan(Select="ALL_ATTRIBUTES")
         for item in result_set:
             print item['attributename']
```

Comment: I tried what you said, i have __getitem__ defined for result_object but If i use 
***table.scan(select="ALL_ATTRIBUTES")***, I get this error : ***UnknownFilterTypeError("Operator 'Select' from 'Select' is not recognized.",)***
and for ***table.scan()***, I get this error : ***JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Requested resource not found', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException'}***